# Where to apply css in .md-dialog-container in component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

which component do I apply the styles of `md-dialog-container`? I tried everything: `app.component.css`, `work-modal.component.css`, `work-details.component.css` and `style.css`. None of these changes the css styling for `md-dialog`. It's working on google chrome dev tools but not working in my project.

Appreciate some help. Thanks.

Here's my file structure:

[image: my file structure]

`work-modal.component.css`

```css
/deep/ .md-dialog-container {
  max-width: 100vw;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  .work-modal-bg {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .modal_title {
    font-size: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .modal_small_title {
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .work_modal_img {
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 500px;
  }

  .work_modal_container {
    position: relative;
  }

  .work_modal_content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -270px;
    right: -130px;
    padding: 60px 55px;
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

`work-details.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { listStateTrigger, listFadeTrigger, listStagTrigger } from './work-animation';
import { Worklistitem } from '.././work.model';
import * as symplCMS from '../../../assets/js/symplcms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CMSService } from '../../../services/cms.service';
import { CMSProvider } from '../../../providers/cms';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import {WorkModalComponent} from '../work-modal/work-modal.component';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-work-details',
  templateUrl: './work-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./work-details.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [
    CMSService,
    CMSProvider
  ],
  animations: [
    listStateTrigger,
    listFadeTrigger,
    listStagTrigger
  ]
})
export class WorkDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
array = [];
dialogResult: String = '';
  constructor(private cmsService: CMSService, public dialog: MdDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cmsService.getCMS(9192, (data) => {
       console.log(data);
       this.initMap(data);
    });

   }

   initMap(data: any) {
     const works = data.works;
     this.array = works;
     console.log(this.array);
   }

   openDialog(id: number) {
     const workObj = this.array[id];
     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WorkModalComponent, {
       width: '1200px',
       data: workObj
     });

     dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog closed: ${result}`);
      this.dialogResult = result;
     });
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `panelClass` option to your `MdDialogConfig`:

```ts
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(WorkModalComponent, {
    width: '1200px',
    data: workObj,
    panelClass: 'my-dialog-container-class' // Replace with your actual dialog container class
});
```

Also, take note that `/deep/` is deprecated and that you should use `::ng-deep` instead.

[More info](https://blog.angular.io/angular-4-3-now-available-8d57b57eb5a8)

Comment: omg, thank you so much!! no wonder it was not working. I'll take note on this.